# UITableviewcell load limited data

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

Curently am working on **UItableview**, am loading data from service but when it comes to excess of data my UI hangs in between for a while. So i want to load first 20 cell and then on scroll other 20 should load and so on.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

your data should be limited then, i.e on every url firing , the data received should be just for 20 cells.

The question is when to fire the url.

Initially the url is fired when the viewController containing the UItableView appears; the subsequent urls should be fired in scrollView didEndScrolling function.

Check out this url [UITableView with infite scrolling and lazy loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273767/uitableview-with-infite-scrolling-and-lazy-loading)