# ios autolayout architecture tips for scrollview

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autolayout

I'm building my first iOS app. I'm kind of stucked when I need to design something a little bit complex ( for me ).

I wan't to reproduce the Youtube App view when you watch a video.
Want I did : 
Pinning a view a top the top.
Added a scroll view that fill the rest of the screen.

But here is the tricky part : 
The scroll view must display videos details, suggested videos, comments.

What I think is to implement suggested videos and comments as two different table views. ( Because I need to put things between )

But the problem is here : The two table views will have their own scrollbar and I don't want that and I'm not able to get the dynamic cells sum heights etc etc ...

Am I in the wrong direction ? Please, how would you setup theses views ?

Thank you

PS : As we scroll down the comments the older must be added and then increase the main scrollview content height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So do you want the suggested videos and comments to share a scrollbar? i.e, you scroll past the suggested videos, and then go into the comments etc?

The simplest solution would be to have one main view, which contains the `UIView` which displays the video at the top, while the bottom half is a `UIContainerView`, which would be linked to a single `UITableViewController` on the storyboard (If you're using storyboards).

The `UITableViewController` has the method `numberOfSectionsInTableView`, which you could set to 3 if you wanted 3 distinct sections (Suggested videos, comments etc).

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` on the `UITableViewController`, you can check which section the cell belongs to with `indexPath.section`, and then degue the appropriate type of cell, which you would have created in the storyboard view.

As for the lazy-loading of comments, there are plenty of resources on this:

[UITableView with infite scrolling and lazy loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273767/uitableview-with-infite-scrolling-and-lazy-loading)

Basically you, just want to load or add more items to your datasource as the user scrolls near to the end of the tableview, and then call `refreshData` on the tableview.

Comment: I figured out a little bit later that it is the best solution, thanks