# MNMBottomPullToRefresh how to load items without dragging

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am working on a table view using MNMBottomPullToRefresh ,i am trying to do some modification in MNMBottomPullToRefresh, in MNMBottomPullToRefresh if you drag table up it will display new data but what i want is when i reach at bottom it  should load data automatically with indicator as below in picture,any one know how to do it ?? Thanks
[image]

Comment: Are you talking about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273767/uitableview-with-infite-scrolling-and-lazy-loading

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented this solution like each api hit gives me 10 results these displays in the table if user scroll to every 7th (7,17,27,...) then I start download another set of 10 records below is the code that way it will not stuck user  and will increase performance.you can remove MBProgressHUD.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSUInteger rowindex=[self.arrayTickets count]-3;
    if (indexPath.row>rowindex)
    {
        NSInteger pageCountTemp=(self.arrayTickets.count/10)+1;
        if (self.pageCount==pageCountTemp)
            return;//no more data to load;
        self.pageCount=pageCountTemp;
        self.isLoadingMore=YES;
        //[MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
        NSNumber* pageNumber=[NSNumber numberWithInteger:self.pageCount];
        NSDictionary* dictParam=@{kAUTH_TOKEN:[[NetworkAPICaller getInstance]getAuthToken],kFETCH_LIMIT:@10,@"pageNo":pageNumber};

        [[NetworkAPICaller getInstance]sendRequestWithParams:dictParam WithDelegate:self forAPI:API_GET_OWNED_TICKETS];
    }
}
```

Comment: i have more then 500+ data in a array whenever i drag up table it will add more 10 but i do not  want that when i scroll at bottom it should load more 10 data process indicator as shown in image

Comment: It will download every 7th like 7, 17, 27, ... or according to your need you can customise this .  -3 is just before 3 records in the existing set to fetch new set. does it make sense to you ?